# convert xls to utf-8 csv using LibreOffice command line?

Tags: libreoffice, file-conversion

I'm trying to batch-convert a bunch of Excel files (.xls) to CSV with UTF-8 encoding. But no matter what I try, nothing seems to happen.

There are a few similar questions about this issue but I guess they are either outdated or wrong, they mostly suggest a variation of this:

```
soffice --convert-to csv --headless --outdir . test.xls
```

(optionally I can also use `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice` instead of `soffice`)

When I execute the above on a shell, from within a directory that contains test.xls, nothing happens. No output, no errors, no .csv file being created, nothing.

Am I missing something? FYI I'm using the latest LibreOffice on OS X.

Comment: Have you tried simply `soffice --convert-to csv test.xls`?  It works on my Windows machine.  Be sure you have write privileges to the current directory.  Also, if you simply type `soffice`, does LibreOffice open?  Finally, be sure that `ls test.xls` really does show that the source file exists.

Comment: Yes, tried that. Didn't work at first. However I think I found the reason, will experiment and update the question or answer myself

Answer (score 3):

Found it, the reason nothing happened is that a GUI instance of LibreOffice was already open!

After closing LibreOffice, the following command line did the trick:

```
soffice --convert-to csv:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)":9,,0,1,1 test.xls
```

The meaning of those numbers in the csv filter flags are explained in detail in the [Open Office Wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options).

Comment: it worked, thanks bro